# is.na() replacing all values instead of na ones

Tags: r, if-statement

I have dataframe `tr` which contins around 1700 rows. I am trying to replace `Type` column values wherever they are `NA` with string `"None"`.

I do a quick count to check how many `NA`s I have in my Type column.

```
na_count = tr[which(is.na(tr$Type)), ]
```

`na_count` contains 8 records.

Now I replace all the `NA`s with `"None"` using

```
ifelse(is.na(tr$Type), tr$Type <- 'None', 0)
```

The above command is replacing all the 1700 rows with None instead of just the 8.
I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: `tr$Type <- ifelse(is.na(tr$Type), 'None', tr$Type)` or `tr$Type[is.na(tr$Type)] <- 'None'`

Comment: "I'm not sure why that is happening" - it's happening because `tr$Type <- "None"` assigns "None" to every element of `tr$Type` on the first occurrence of an NA value.

Comment: @neilfws shouldn't it execute the `tr$Type <- "None"` only and only if the `if` condition is true and not every element?

Comment: @alistaire can you post it as answer? It worked. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I've got a personal policy that I only write answers if there's a full [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) in the question